# Why can't $\rm N_2$ TEA lasers produce optical breakdown? (sparks in the air)

Tags: optics, laser

I've been googling around and I can't find any direct explanation of why N2 TEA lasers are never shown to be used to demonstrate optical(dielectric?) breakdown or sparks in the air.

Would someone please help me understand what it is about N2 TEA lasers that make optical breakdown difficult/impossible?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE and don't ask me to recommend a site to ask this sort of question on because I don't know.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d19dM8ZB3Qs

Comment: I suspect that that would thar require more voltage gradient at the electrodes than the air can withstand

Comment: @JohnMeacham that comment was made before it was migrated here. Checking things first is always a good thing to do. Mind you you've been an SE member nearly as long as me so you should know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is simpler than you think.

Just like CO2 lasers do not produce a visual breakdown of atmospheric air (or most other IR lasers), TEA lasers operate in the ultraviolet range: 337.1 nm.

This answers in theory why weak lasers would not breakdown air, but why don't strong lasers break down air?

This is because of limitations of electrical properties of the materials used in construction of the laser. There are major two factors that impact the power of a TEA laser:

- The atmospheric makeup of the resonator cavity
- The dE/dt of the resonator cavity

Paradoxically, the same factors that would increase the power of a TEA laser via changing the atmospheric makeup also force a decrease in dE/dt. This limits the practical power for any given length of laser cavity, and thus many TEA lasers could not achieve atmospheric breakdown under perfect conditions.

This is in combination with the fact that the coherence of TEA lasers is, franky, doodoo, and with all other factors, it comes down to the simple fact:

The power per area of TEA laser beam does not exceed the requirement to break down air, it *is* possible, but the construction required may be hundreds of feet in length to garner enough power, and that is impractical to put into a light N2 vacuum.